# Questions about Spring 2.5 and Java 6

Tags: java, spring

I’m going to start writing my application for athletes based on Spring 2.5.6 and Java 6 (as I’ve read that Java 7 is less compatibile with this Spring version). I’ve couple of questions as I’m not familiar with such an old versions. (I need to write it for my Engineer’s Thesis – comparing app written in old version of Spring and in newest version of Sping Boot)

1. I know already I need web.xml, but do I need servlets  to handle http requests or there is some other common way to do it? I won’t have any front sides (like jsp files) – just backend.
   I mean, I want to build the most common app based on Spring 2.5 and java 6 and to do it I need these two things to do any request, right?
2. What about declaring beans in these versions. Do I need to do it in xml like …. or I can annotate class with for example @Component (as @Service propably does not exist in this version). Which way should I go? I would like the differences to be most visible - beetwen spring boot and old spring, so declaring beans in xml would be fine (as in SpringBoot I have annotation like @Service, @Repository etc) -  but it’s hard to explain in my Engineer's Thesis why I’ve chosen for example declaring beans in xml when I could do it easily with annotations.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2007/11/19/spring-framework-2-5-released

Comment: Are you sure you want Spring 2.5? Looking at the [mvn repo for Spring Boot](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter) the most recent version of Spring Boot is version 2.3.2 but Spring itself is currently at 5.2.8 according to [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core). Were you thinking of Spring Boot or do you really want to use Spring 2.5?

Comment: @TrecApps I really want to use Spring 2.5. Why you asking?

Comment: Again to confirm Spring framework version and spring boot version are two different things. Are you sure you want to use spring 2.5 not spring boot 2.5? If you are creating a fresh application you should go with the latest stable version, rather than using old version